# DAX MIN on Measure results in 0 without 0 in table

Tags: powerbi, dax

The detailed data with booth space per customer comes from the table [ExhibitorClass_Details]. The measure `[Class_Booth_Space_ALL]` classifies the customer by booth space to A,B,C or D.
To be able to use this measure in visuals I have a [Class] table as well with the static values A,B,C and D.
I need to find the MAX, MIN, AVG... booth space per Class.
To calculate the MAX booth space per classicication I have created this measure:

```
Visual Count Class MAX Booth Space ALL = 
  VAR _rank_class = SELECTEDVALUE('Class'[Class]) 
  return MAXX('ExhibitorClass_Details', if([Class_Booth_Space_ALL] = _rank_class,
               calculate(MAX(ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV])),0))
```

My measure gives the right results for MAX.

But the wrong result for MIN:
[image]

```
Visual Count Class MIN Booth Space ALL = 
  VAR _rank_class = SELECTEDVALUE('Class'[Class]) 
  return MINX('ExhibitorClass_Details', if([Class_Booth_Space_ALL] = _rank_class,
               calculate(MAX(ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV])),0))
```

Instead of giving me the MIN for every class (as shown in red) it just results in 0.

```
Visual Count Class MIN Booth Space ALL = 
  VAR _rank_class = SELECTEDVALUE('Class'[Class]) 
  return MINX('ExhibitorClass_Details', if([Class_Booth_Space_ALL] = _rank_class,
               calculate(MIN(ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV])),0))
```

I have also tried a second version but it gives the same 0 results.
Can anyone please help me.

Here is the example [ExhibitorClass_Details] data:

```
|Costomer_Name|Booth_Space_ALLPREV|
|Megatech|30|
|CyberMunch|210|
|Digiwell|410|
|Innovix|110|
|Cloudmore|1410|
|Systemiq|610|
|Smartsoft|150|
|Clickwell|2410|
|Weblund|170|
|Quanterra|90|
|Avantex|270|
|Ventura|150|
|Sphere|450|
|Bitling|70|
|Elementaliq|130|
```

here are the cut offs:

```
|A|2000|
|B|1000|
|C|500|
|D|0|
```

and the Cut Off measure for the classification:

```
Class_Booth_Space_ALL = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    SUMX(ExhibitorClass_Details, ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV]) >= [Booth Space ALL A CutOff],"A",
    SUMX(ExhibitorClass_Details, ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV]) >= [Booth Space ALL B CutOff]
    && SUMX(ExhibitorClass_Details, ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV]) < [Booth Space ALL A CutOff],"B",
    SUMX(ExhibitorClass_Details, ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV]) >= [Booth Space ALL C CutOff]
    && SUMX(ExhibitorClass_Details, ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV]) < [Booth Space ALL B CutOff],"C",
    SUMX(ExhibitorClass_Details, ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV]) >= [Booth Space ALL D CutOff]
    && SUMX(ExhibitorClass_Details, ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV]) < [Booth Space ALL C CutOff],"D",
    "N/A")
```

Comment: Copiable data tables, even if reduced and not your real data, are far better than pictures.

Comment: Example data and Classification measure are awailable now.

Comment: Thanks. Are the CutOff measures all similar in nature? Can you share one of them?

Comment: CutOffs are added awailable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your current constructions for *Visual Count Class MAX Booth Space ALL* and *Visual Count Class MIN Booth Space ALL*. Unless I'm missing something, they seem to unnecessarily employ both `MIN` and `MINX`.

I would have used something like:

```
Visual Count Class MIN Booth Space ALL =
VAR _rank_class =
    SELECTEDVALUE( 'Class'[Class] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        MIN( ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV] ),
        FILTER(
            ExhibitorClass_Details,
            [Class_Booth_Space_ALL] = _rank_class
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Visual Count Class MIN Booth Space ALL = 
VAR _rank_class = SELECTEDVALUE('Class'[Class]) 
return
CALCULATE(
  MIN( ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV] ),
  ALL( ExhibitorClass_Details ),
  ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV] = _rank_class,
  ExhibitorClass_Details[Booth_Space_ALLPREV] > 0
)
```